# How to access focused element programmatically WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, controls

Wondering how should I access elements property which does have the focus. I have found the following code to find the focused element :

```
var focusedControl = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this);
```

This seems to work well, in debug "focusedcontrol" is the right element however I don't know how to access it programmatically. Something like :

```
focusedControl.Text = "txt";
```

The reason why I wanna do this - in the same window as the TextBoxes I have several Buttons which form a keypad. After hitting the Button (Focusable = False) I want to get reference to focused TextBox and insert the corresponding digit in TextBox.Text.

Thanks
Lukas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GetFocusedElement()` method returns `IInputElement`, not a `TextBox`.

Since `FrameworkElement` implements `IInputElement`, and `Control` (and `TextBox`) are derived from `FrameworkElement`, you can just cast the result to a `TextBox` yourself:

```
var focusedControl = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this);

var tBox = focusedControl as TextBox;

if (tBox != null)
    tBox.Text = "txt";
```